# I want to display my 2. latest post

Tags: blog

[image]Hi,

Does anybody know a plugin or a way to show not the latest but the 2. and 3. latest post.

Comment: How are you adding these posts? As a widget, in a template, in your header or footer files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:
It will display the second and third latest posts.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' =>'2',
'offset' => 1
));


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

     the_title(); 
     the_excerpt();

   endwhile; 
  wp_reset_postdata(); 

else : 
     __('No post found');
endif;
```